# Error in creating AMA style references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors

I am a very beginner in LaTeX trying to generate references using style AMA  (American Medical Association) and here is sample code. `UM.bib` contains reference `p1`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{UM}
\bibliographystyle{ama}
\cite{p1}
\end{document}
```

I am using BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) on Windows 10, TeXstudio. I am getting compile time error as

```
I couldn't open style file ama.bst
---line 3 of file UM.aux
 : \bibstyle{ama
 :              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file UM.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

I tried copying file ama.bst from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc?lang=en. Then created  a folder `ama` at `...\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst` and put this file `ama.bst` there. Still, no luck.

Can anyone help? By the way, the ama.bst file is still in alpha version, could not find a newer file.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should never install files not in the distribution in the main TeXMF root. Instead, you should create a local TeXMF root, say C:\LocalTeXMF, preferably as Administrator if you want everyone using your computer has access to these files.

This can be done via `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, `Roots` tab. Such a local root must be organised to repect the TDS (`TeX Directory Structure`). In the  present case, copying the localisation on CTAN, it should be in `LocalTeXRoot\bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst`

[image]

2) Refresh the `file names database` used by TeX to find the files used at
 compilation time (MiKTeX Settings, `General` tab, `Refresh FNDB` button).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I could not understand it. It seems that I need to check from beginning, local TeXMF root and how to create it. In the meanwhile, I just copied the file in the working directory and seems working. If you have a beginner procedure to follow your answer, please write that.

Comment: Of course, if `ama.bst` is in the working directory, it will compile. But what for a  new document in another directory? You'll have to make another copy in the new working directory? You just have to create a new directory from Windows explorer, then declare it to MiKTeX as a new root, just clicking on the `Add` button in MiKTeX Settings (1st image). I can assure you it's very simple. What's not so simple for beginners is to understand the TeX Directory Structure, but in the present case,  I wrote wher to put your file.

Answer (score 1):

I will quickly clarify @Bernard's answer for beginners to grasp it.This is only for windows users with MiKTex sorry :)
Steps

1)Go to your C drive and create the folder `LocalTexMF` you then have the complete path name as `C:\LocalTexMF`

2) Go to `run` and run the command "mo_admin.exe" (or you could just search for MiKTeX Settings (Admin), you will get the following image. 
[image]

Click on the Roots tab and below you can add the folder you created in 1), i.e, `C:\LocalTexMF`

3) Put the `ama.bst` in this root folder, so that MiKTeX will find it when it searches for this file.

4) Go to the General tab per the image below
[image]

Click on refresb FNDB to refresh all files so that the changes you have made to the file system are known to MiKTeX.